# Is anyone successfully editing .vbs scripts in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: vbscript

I'd like to do some VB Scripting and am looking for a good editor. It occurs to me that I might be able to just edit it with VS 2005.

Are you using VS 2005 to edit .vbs scripts?
Any pointers on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this pointer but haven't started using it yet:
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/bb28fc96-36ae-4590-aedf-b7eb75fe1526

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

While I imagine you could probably write VB scripts in VS 2005, I'm not sure what the benefit would be. There is no support for VB scripts built-in to the IDE, nor will the debugger be of use.

If you are looking for an editor with a debugger for VB Scripts, check out [VbsEdit](https://www.vbsedit.com/).

I use [notepad++](https://web.archive.org/web/20110823102854/http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm), which supports [auto-completion](https://web.archive.org/web/20100306005441/http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net:80/uk/auto-completion-HOWTO.php).

Also, check out [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/). I have not used it much, but it does support auto-completion as well.

Comment: Thanks. I have VBSEdit but it doesn't do autocomplete and I'm totally spoiled by Delphi, VB6 and VB.net ;-)